Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$
I'm studying the convergence of the following series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right).$$
I found out that $\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right) > \frac{1}{k^{2/3}}$ if $k>4$ using Desmos (how do I prove that?).
That lets me evaluate the original sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right) > \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\frac{1}{k^{2/3}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k} \space \text{which clearly diverges}$$
Are there easier ways to say that the serie diverges or is there a simple way to prove the inequality above?

Using the fact that $\log(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\to 0$, you have:
$$\frac1{k^{1/3}}\log\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt k}\right)\sim\frac1{k^{1/3}}\frac1{k^{1/2}}=\frac1{k^{5/6}} $$
You conclude applying the comparison test.

I had the same idea, but $\frac{1}{k^{5/6}} > \frac{1}{k^{1/3}}ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$, so I cannot use the comparison test, can I? As I need a divergent serie which is strictly smaller than the one I'm studying

@Avgustine see this for example

@Avgustine if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are (say) positive and if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n/b_n >0$ then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum b_n$ converges - you can easily verify this using the comparison test (namely: a convergent sequence is bounded)

As an alternative, we can use the inequality as $x\to 0$
$$\ln(1+x)\ge x-\frac{x^2}2$$
then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\ge \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{5/6}}-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4/3}}$$

Just for your curiosity.
If you use the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$$
$$S_n \sim 6 n^{1/6}+C+\frac{3}{2n^{1/3}} +\frac{1}{10 n^{5/6}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{7/6}}\right)$$ For this level of expansion
$$C=-\frac{72252627611}{16124313600}-\frac{\sqrt{3} \pi }{2}+\frac{124337 \log   (2)}{236196}$$
Trying for $n=1000$, this limited expansion gives $S_{1000}=\color{red}{12.287}19$
Edit
If we use the continuous case
$$I_n=\int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^{1/3}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\,dk$$ and expand the result as a series
$$I_n \sim 6 n^{1/6}-\frac{9+\sqrt{3} \pi}{2}+\frac{3}{2n^{1/3}}+\frac{2}{5 n^{5/6}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right)$$
